# Unable to open jupyter notebook in localhost in ubuntu

Tags: localhost, jupyter-notebook, http-status-code-503

I installed jupyter notebook and ran the command

```
$jupyter notebook
```

and it gave a message as follows

```
[I 23:54:40.063 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/kv
[I 23:54:40.063 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 23:54:40.063 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:2323/
[I 23:54:40.063 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

but when I go to the `localhost:2323`

I get the error message stating...

```
503 Service Unavailable

Failed to connect to server localhost
```

How do I resolve this and get my jupyter notebook running ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, and I realized that it was my proxy setting that was causing the problem. Clear the proxy setting of your browser and try again.